# 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added exception breakpoints and it always blows up on this line

> BookPage *page = _sections[path.section].pages[path.row];

Bare in mind I'm new in objective-c

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did You check, that Your Array contain elements. It  seems  `_section` is an outlet. Is it connected in Storyboard or Interfacebuilder?

Comment: The error says you are trying to get the second item of an array which doesn't contain 2 items.

Comment: @ivion no it's not connected to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code have two places where this `Exception` one is `_sections[path.section]` and another is the full code.

First check the `_sections` contains the pages array of that position `path.section`. If contains then check count the `pages` count and then try to get the row value.

Like this:

```
if ([_sections count] > path.section){
    if ([_sections[path.section].pages count] > path.row){
        BookPage *page = _sections[path.section].pages[path.row];
    }
}
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you m8, appreciate it